# Rewrite dynamic URL to static one in .htaccess from wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, dynamic-url, wp-rewrite

I want to rewrite dynamic url:

```
/location.php?c=city&s=state
```

to be static:

```
/location-city-state
```

In the same folder on the same domain. I have tried the code bellow:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule location-(.*)-(.*) location.php?c=$1&s=$2  
</IfModule>
```

But the problem is that it is a **Wordpress** site and it doesn't work with wordpress .htaccess in my case. When I go to the /location-city-state it gives me 404, how can I fix this?

Here is the start of the .htaccess:

```
#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  
</IfModule>
```

I've tried adding the rewrite code before the beginning of the wordpress code and after it but it still won't work.

Comment: You have to use wp-rewrite api for that I think It is not a htaccess problem.

Comment: Thank you, you are a lifesaver, I added:
`function custom_rewrite_rule() {  
    add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]*)-([^/]*)-location/?', 'location.php?c=$1&s=$2','top');  
  }  
  add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);  `
  
to the **functions.php** and it works like a charm.  
For anyone else having the same problem,  
 visit: [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule#Using_Custom_Templates_with_custom_querystring)